# Symfony 5: Ajax pagination without bundle

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I am on Symfony 5.4. I want to create Ajax pagination for the blog posts home page. I have already created a pagination in PHP which works. Here are my files:

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/accueil-blog", name="show_blog_home_general")
 */
public function showGeneral(Request $request, BlogHomeRepository $blogHomeRepo, PostRepository $postRepo)
{
 
    $limit = 2;
 
    $page = (int)$request->query->get('page', 1);
 
    /*nouveau */
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $page = $_POST['PagePagination'];
    }
    /*fin nouveau */
 
    $blogPosts = $postRepo->findForPagination($page, $limit);
    $totalBlogPosts = $postRepo->getTotalBlogPosts();
    $blogHomes = $blogHomeRepo->findForMenu();
 
    if (!$blogPosts | !$blogHomes) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }
 
    /*nouveau */
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->json($blogPosts);
    }
    /*fin nouveau */
 
    return $this->render('blog/home_general.html.twig', compact('blogPosts', 'totalBlogPosts', 'limit', 'page', 'blogHomes'));
}
```

JS file (Jquery):

```
let PagePagination = 1;
$('.button--load').on('click', function(e){
  PagePagination++;
  $.ajax({
      url: '',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          'PagePagination' : PagePagination
      },
      beforeSend: function(data) {
          console.log('beforeSend', data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
          console.log('error', error);
      },
      success: function(data) {
          console.log('succes', data);
      },
      complete: function(data) {
          console.log('complete', data);
      }
  })
})
```

The template file displays all blog posts. It is a home page for blog posts. Here is what I have in the console:

```
succes (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

I get the number of objects I want (2), but the objects are empty or I can't print them...

I tried with string or int data, it works.

Thank you for your answers :).

Comment: Are you sure they are empty ? I think you can expand your array and the objects in the console

Comment: @VincentDecaux, no, I'm not sure. As I wrote in the message, maybe I can't print it in the console.